# mySQL Group (show 1 member only once)

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to fetch list of who messaged a user or who user messaged to.

```
SELECT messages.* 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(lastseen) AS lastseen 
    FROM messages
    WHERE '".$user."' IN (from,to)
    GROUP BY IF ('".$user."' = from,to,from)
) AS latest
LEFT JOIN messages 
USING(lastseen) 
ORDER BY lastseen desc,(read='no' and to='".$user."') limit 10
```

This works, however, it shows some users twice.

[image]

What is the correct way to show a user only once ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT messages.* 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(lastseen) AS lastseen 
    FROM messages
    WHERE '".$user."' IN (from,to)
    GROUP BY IF ('".$user."' = from,to,from)
) AS latest
LEFT JOIN messages 
USING(lastseen) 
ORDER BY lastseen desc,(read='no' and to='".$user."') limit 10
```